# Will TLP work with HWE kernel?

Tags: battery, tlp, hardware-enablement-stack

I'm currently on Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm using TLP to set the battery charge threshold on my ThinkPad. I've read around that now it should be possible to have kernel 5.8 with HWE, so I decided to switch to this new kernel. But before that I need to know if TLP will work with this kernel. Can anyone suggest me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLP will happily work with any kernel.

Disclaimer: I'm TLP's author.

Comment: Will TLP also work with manually installed kernels (like [mainline kernels](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D))?

Comment: Yes, of course. Which part of "any" is misleading?